# How do I build a valid JQuery selector using variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to build a jQuery selector. This involves concatenating string and variables. However, for some reason, the resulting selector comes up invalid. I have attempted a number of options such as this:

```
$('[name="[name='$radioName + (row_id) + ']"][value="$result"]').attr('checked',true);
```

`$radioName` example is: 'Nigeria[Osun][Okuku-;// the angle bracket is not closed as the row_id will be appended to it before the closing bracket is appended as shown above.

`$result` example is: '67

`row_id` example is: 5

How may I build a valid descriptor with these requirements?

Thanks

Comment: Selectors are nothing but strings. Stack Overflow's syntax highlighter already reveals some of the syntax errors.

Comment: `[name="[name=...]]` isn't valid. Can't place an attribute selector inside an attribute selector (unless `[name=...]` is the attribute's value.)

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: Thanks, have you got an idea what may be wrong with the example above and how I may fix it? I don't think I saw the syntax highlighter you referred to. Thanks

Comment: @BradChristie: Thanks. The construction of the name is the offending bit but here's my approach. $radioName is the name (in part) of the element. In this case it may be Nigeria[Kwara][Ilorin- again the hyphen is part of the name but the last bracket is intentionally missing. This is to be added later after adding the row_id - which may be an integer. The resulting name becomes: Nigeria[Kwara][Ilorin-3] or Nigeria[Kwara][Ilorin-9]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('[name="' + $radioName + row_id + ']' + '"][value="' + $result + '"]').attr('checked',true);
```

When I'm putting together concatenated expressions, using I write the static text with proper quotes first.  Something like:

```
$('[name=""][value=""]').attr('checked',true);
```

Then I paste in `'+ +'` in each of the spots I want to add a variable. Like so:

```
$('[name="'+ +'"][value="'+ +'"]').attr('checked',true);
```

Then lastly, I add the variable:

```
$('[name="'+ $radioName + row_id + ']' + '"][value="'+ $result +'"]').attr('checked',true);
```

Comment: Thanks but I tried this and got the error:                        SyntaxError: missing ] in index expression
...Nigeria[Kwara][Ilorin- + row_id + '"]][value="' + 7 + '"]').attr('checked',true)

Comment: @pi: I edited my answer to include the closing bracket for the one included in $radioName. By the way, It's best to avoid storing single brackets.  It's much better to leave them out of the variable and put the pair of them explicitly in the expression as text.  Much less confusing.

Comment: thanks again, but that still didn't work. I wish it did. From my observation, js seem to complain about: $radioName = 'Nigeria[Kwara][Ilorin-'; Then doing a console.log($radioName); it fails. Could that be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: @pi: what I'd try next would be to do a selection with the actual text rather than variables. That way you'll know if the issue is the variable or the substitution. So: `$('[name="Nigeria[Osun][Okuku5]"][value="67"]').attr('checked',true)`

Comment: thanks. I actually did that a long while - trying to debug the code. Thanks though

Comment: Had to not use array-based names eventually, ideas from @dnagirl helped

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to split the selection and comparison like so:

```
$('[name][value]') // select all elements that have both name and value attributes
    .each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        if ($this.attr('name') == 'whatever' && $this.attr('value') == 'result') {
            $this.prop('checked', true);
        }
    });
```

Or filter them:

```
$('[name][value]') // select all elements that have both name and value attributes
    .filter(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        return $this.attr('name') == 'whatever' && $this.attr('value') == 'result';
    })
    .prop('checked', true);
```